# TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, torchvision, dataloader

Trying to put the saliency map to the image and make a new data set

```
trainloader = utilsxai.load_data_cifar10(batch_size=1,test=False)
testloader =  utilsxai.load_data_cifar10(batch_size=128, test=True)
```

this load_cifar10 is torchvision

```
data = trainloader.dataset.data 

trainloader.dataset.data = (data * sal_maps_hf).reshape(data.shape)
```

> sal_maps_hf shape with (50000,32,32,3) 
>  and trainloader shape
> with (50000,32,32,3)

but when I run this

```
for idx,img in enumerate(trainloader):
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
last) ~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)    2644             typekey = (1, 1) + shape[2:], arr["typestr"]
-> 2645             mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]    2646         except KeyError:

KeyError: ((1, 1, 3), '<f4')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-142-9410d0967245> in <module>
----> 1 show_images(trainloader)

<ipython-input-117-a32f5bd33032> in show_images(trainloader)
      1 def show_images(trainloader):
----> 2     for idx,(img,target) in enumerate(trainloader):
      3         img = img.squeeze()
      4         #pritn(img)
      5         img = torch.tensor(img)

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in
__next__(self)
    344     def __next__(self):
    345         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 346         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    347         if self._pin_memory:
    348             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/cifar.py in
__getitem__(self, index)
    120         # doing this so that it is consistent with all other datasets
    121         # to return a PIL Image
--> 122         img = Image.fromarray(img)
    123 
    124         if self.transform is not None:

~/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)    2645             mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]  2646         except KeyError:
-> 2647             raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")    2648     else:    2649         rawmode = mode

TypeError: Cannot handle this data type


    trainloader.dataset.__getitem__

<bound method CIFAR10.__getitem__ of Dataset CIFAR10
    Number of datapoints: 50000
    Root location: /mnt/3CE35B99003D727B/input/pytorch/data
    Split: Train
    StandardTransform Transform: Compose(
               Resize(size=32, interpolation=PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
               ToTensor()
           )
```

Comment: Are you sure your `dataloader` stores the data as an `nd.array` ot `torch.tensor`? It seems like your data is stored as `PIL.Image`s.

Comment: data=trainloader.dataset.data  says numpy.ndarray

Comment: I think the type does not matter just assign the new dataset has some way to do it..

Comment: yet the error you get comes from `PIL.Image`... are you sure `dataset.__getitem__` actually uses `dataset.data`? is it possible there is an additional representation of the data? you'll have to look at the code of the dataset.

Comment: trainloader.dataset.__getitem__ :: <bound method CIFAR10.__getitem__ of Dataset CIFAR10
    Number of datapoints: 50000
    Root location: /mnt/3CE35B99003D727B/input/pytorch/data
    Split: Train
    StandardTransform
Transform: Compose(
               Resize(size=32, interpolation=PIL.Image.BILINEAR)
               ToTensor()
           )>

Comment: what is the `dtype` of `dataset.data` **before** the change? and after? what is the `dtype` of `sal_maps_hf`?

Comment: type(trainloader.dataset.data)  = numpy.ndarray
:: type(trainloader.dataset) = torchvision.datasets.cifar.CIFAR10

Comment: I check the both type but type is the same

Comment: you checked the `type` not the `dtype`: `dataset.data.dtype` and `sal_maps_hf.dtype`

Comment: BTW, why don't you [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code in your comments?

Comment: "trainloader = utilsxai.load_data_cifar10(batch_size=1,test=False)  mask = np.random.rand(50000,32,32,3) <br/>trainloader.dataset.data = mask <br/> for idx,(img,target) in enumerate(trainloader):
    img = img.squeeze() "<br/> this will give you the same error  try it

Comment: not sure how to put the next line format in comment

Comment: not sure it is possible in comments. but you can use "`" to indicate code

Comment: trainloader = utilsxai.load_data_cifar10(batch_size=1,test=False)
  testloader =  utilsxai.load_data_cifar10(batch_size=128, test=True)
mask = np.random.rand(50000,32,32,3)
trainloader.dataset.data = mask * trainloader.dataset.data 
or 
trainloader.dataset.data = mask 
for idx,(img,target) in enumerate(trainloader):
   something "
will show you the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sal_maps_hf` is not `np.uint8`.

Based on the partial information in the question and in comments, I guess that your mask is of `dtype` `np.float` (or similar), and by multiplying `data * sal_maps_hf` your data is cast to `dtype` other than `np.uint8` which later makes `PIL.Image` to throw an exception.

Try:

```py
trainloader.dataset.data = (data * sal_maps_hf).reshape(data.shape).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: omg you sloved it. how you check the dtype of sal_maps_hf  type(sal_maps_hf) only shows its numpy.array

Comment: @jakeMonk it's **not** the [`type`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-type-function/) but rather the [`dtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html). `dtype` is the "type" of the elements of the `ndarray` (or the `tensor`).

Comment: I see , sal_maps_hf.dtype = dtype('<f4')

Comment: @jakeMonk as expected. `uint8` is a very restrictive data type. Make sure the data after the casting is not corrupted beyond repair for your needs.

Comment: thank you i did not even know '<f4' is some type... haha

Comment: I see I should know more about the data type thank you Shai